# Change font size in a latex book format

Tags: fonts

I have looked around here for solutions, and tried many, but nothing works. I would like to change the font size to 10, no to tiny or large etc for this book.

Is it possible with the given preamble?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
% A6: 1.03, 2.305, 1.33, 1.73
\usepackage[top=1.83cm, bottom=2.105cm, outer=2.13cm, inner=2.53cm, headsep=7pt, a5paper]{geometry}
%Bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yfonts}

% Custom section/chapter titles
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% Drawing
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{pstricks}

% Fonts


%custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Custom background
\usepackage{background}

% Multi column
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multicolrule}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}

% Table of contents
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    linktoc=all,
}

\usepackage{pbox}
%\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility}]{microtype}

\newcommand{\numcolumns}{1}
\newcommand{\lettrinelines}{5}
\linespread{0.8}

\input{formatting/formatting.tex}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 10 what? The default font size of `book` is already 10pt. So you even would not need the used option `10pt`. And if you've changed the font size somewhere using, e.g., `\small` you can switch back to 10pt with `\normalsize`. So, sorry, but I think, I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Please add `formatting.tex` .

Comment: 10 pt, are there other units? I tried to go down to 8 but  no chance

Comment: You cannot set  arbitrary font sizes in standard documents,  if you really need  8pt as default font size, run `texdoc extsizes`.

Comment: Thanks Fran, I will try this out!